# Visual Studio not recognizing __AVX2__ or __AVX__

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, macros, simd

I'm implementing a simple SIMD wrapper in C++.
To make it cross-platform, I use CMake to set-up the project with Visual Studio

I've added /Arch:AVX2, but Visual Studio does not recognize `__AVX2__` Macro.

First, my CMake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.2)

set(INCLUDEDIR "include/Maths")
set(SOURCEDIR "src")

set(HEADER_FILES
    ${INCLUDEDIR}/export.h 
    ${INCLUDEDIR}/SIMDWrapper/Config/SIMDConfig.h)

set(SOURCE_FILES 
    ${SOURCEDIR}/Application.cpp)


add_library(Maths SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES}  ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Maths PUBLIC Core)
target_include_directories(Maths PUBLIC "include")
target_compile_options(Maths PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:/arch:AVX2>)
target_compile_definitions(Maths PRIVATE MATHS_EXPORT)
```

And my Header File (from Agner Fog's VectorClass [`instrset.h`](https://github.com/darealshinji/vectorclass/blob/master/instrset.h)):

```
#pragma once
#if (defined(_M_AMD64) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__amd64)) && ! 
    defined(__x86_64__)
#define __x86_64__ 1
#endif


#ifndef SIMD_INSTR_SET
#if defined (__AVX2__)
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 8
#elif defined ( __AVX__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 7
#elif defined ( __SSE4_2__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 6
#elif defined ( __SSE4_1__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 5
#elif defined ( __SSSE3__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 4
#elif defined ( __SSE3__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 3
#elif defined ( __SSE2__ ) || defined ( __x86_64__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 2 //this is where the color has changed
#elif defined ( __SSE__ )
    #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 1
#elif defined ( _M_IX86_FP )    
   #define SIMD_INSTR_SET _M_IX86_FP
#else
   #define SIMD_INSTR_SET 0
#endif // instruction set defines
#endif // SIMD_INSTR_SET
```

This is what I did.
`__x86_64__` is defined, my CPU is i5 Skylake so it should support AVX2.

I've checked if Advanced Vector Extensions 2 option is enabled from Project Configuration Properties, and it is enabled.

Is there something I need to change/add from CMake or Visual Studio to make the AVX2 Macro recognizable?

Comment: Try adding a ``#error test`` statement to the ``__AVX2__`` clause and build to see if it really is set or not. Depending on exactly which version of Visual Studio you are running, the IntelliSense compiler is sometimes (too often) a bit behind the actual C++ compiler so you can get false colorization results. Also, support for ``/arch:AVX2`` was added as of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. Which version Visual Studio are you actually using?

Comment: Hello! sorry for late reply, I use VS 2017(2018 Dec 18 Update).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn And Yes, E0035 for #error directive AVX is not set at all.

Comment: I'd check your command  line output then to see what's ending up there...

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I just chose to do the tests(which one is supported from my system) from CMake and add my own compile definition. This way, I don't need to worry about Macros. Thank you!

Comment: If ``__AVX2__`` is not defined, then you aren't build with ``/arch:AVX2`` with the Visual C++ or Intel compiler.

Comment: Can you try out the generator expression `$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/arch:AVX2>` and if that doesn't work adding the "/arch:AVX2" compile option without using a generator expression? I often use a `add_definition(/arch:SSE2)` to enable a package wide setting.

Comment: Your header file looks exactly like [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) Vector Class `instrset.h` ([github mirror](https://github.com/darealshinji/vectorclass/blob/master/instrset.h)). 
 Be aware that it's GPLed.  If you copy code from it, your library also needs to be GPLed.  (Unless you and Agner both got that block of instruction-set macro checking from a common other source.)  Anyway, MSVC doesn't define macros for most levels of SSE, e.g. SSSE3, but it does define `__AVX__` and `__AVX2__` if enabled.

Comment: @PeterCordes I used it to test Macros, my header is completely different now, with my own macros. Thanx for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to enable the compile option `/arch:AVX2` to your target (if it is supported by your compiler).

Either by using a generator expression

```
target_compile_options(Maths PRIVATE $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/arch:AVX2>)
```

or by setting the compile option in a `if` clause

```
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(Maths PRIVATE /arch:AVX2)
endif()
```

or by using an `add_definitions` call to add the definitions to all targets that are created in the script after this command

```
if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(/arch:AVX2)
endif()
```

I try to avoid using generator expressions if not absolutely necessary as they do not improve readability of the CMake script files and are sometimes hard to get right.